# How to create relative url usable between different deployments

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple aspnet core web app that I run locally at my root `http://localhost/` and I'm publishing it to my IIS server which is `http://192.168.1.100/MyApp` when I click on any links, I'm always brought to the root of the domain and not my sub-app.

I've tried relative urls like `href='/home/index'`, `href='home/index'` but they work in one place and not another.

Is there a way to accomplish this with either vanilla html or some razor?

Answer (score 1):

Toss a tilde (`~`) in front of any links you're creating with Razor, which will make the link relative to the app's root.

Comment: This works but do you know if there's a native way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you give a little more detail as to what you mean? Using the tilde is the standard way of doing this with Razor.

Comment: I meant using straight HTML. Razor is all server side and needs to be compiled so I can't use it in static files.